# Icon for menu item from layout

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/nav_items">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_home"
            android:title="Second host home" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I want to use my `icon.xml` as the icon for the items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="icon1"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I am trying to set the menu item icon as my `icon.xml` in the `OnViewCreated` method like this:

```
public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    var navigationView = view.FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_home).SetChecked(true);

    var icon = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.icon, null, false);
    icon.Layout(icon.Left, icon.Top, icon.Right, icon.Bottom);
    icon.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textview).Text = "icon2";
    icon.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
    var iconDrawable = new  BitmapDrawable(icon.GetDrawingCache(true));
    icon.DrawingCacheEnabled = false;
    navigationView.Menu.GetItem(0).SetIcon(iconDrawable);
}
```

But it's not working. It takes space where the icon is supposed to be, but it's blank. Any idea why? I'm writing this app in Xamarin.Android, but it's identical to native Android so an answer in either would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_basket_spinner"
    android:title="title"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/your_layout"/>
```

Comment: That puts `your_layout` at the far right of the item, instead of on the left.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to combine the icon and title of the item into a single layout, and use that instead?

Comment: You can do any layout, but you should use `app:actionLayout="@layout/your_layout"`. Try else to add this attributes: `android:orderInCategory="1"` `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Using `actionLayout` and removing `title` works. I just had to set the width/height of the root element in `your_layout` to `match_parent`. But what is a "actionLayout" ?

Answer (score -1):

For menu item with icon, first create a JAVA file (IconizedMenu.java),

```
/**
 * Created by PatelD on 04-10-2017.
 */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPresenter;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class IconizedMenu implements MenuBuilder.Callback, MenuPresenter.Callback {
    private Context mContext;
    private MenuBuilder mMenu;
    private View mAnchor;
    private MenuPopupHelper mPopup;
    private OnMenuItemClickListener mMenuItemClickListener;
    private OnDismissListener mDismissListener;

    /**
     * Callback interface used to notify the application that the menu has closed.
     */
    public interface OnDismissListener {
        /**
         * Called when the associated menu has been dismissed.
         *
         * @param menu The PopupMenu that was dismissed.
         */
        public void onDismiss(IconizedMenu menu);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new PopupMenu.
     *
     * @param context Context for the PopupMenu.
     * @param anchor  Anchor view for this popup. The popup will appear below the anchor if there
     *                is room, or above it if there is not.
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public IconizedMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
        mContext = context;
        mMenu = new MenuBuilder(context);
        mMenu.setCallback(this);
        mAnchor = anchor;
        mPopup = new MenuPopupHelper(context, mMenu, anchor);
        mMenu.setCallback(this);
        mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return the {@link android.view.Menu} associated with this popup. Populate the returned Menu with
     * items before calling {@link #show()}.
     * @see #show()
     * @see #getMenuInflater()
     */
    public Menu getMenu() {
        return mMenu;
    }

    /**
     * @return a {@link android.view.MenuInflater} that can be used to inflate menu items from XML into the
     * menu returned by {@link #getMenu()}.
     * @see #getMenu()
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return new SupportMenuInflater(mContext);
    }

    /**
     * Inflate a menu resource into this PopupMenu. This is equivalent to calling
     * popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, popupMenu.getMenu()).
     *
     * @param menuRes Menu resource to inflate
     */
    public void inflate(int menuRes) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, mMenu);
    }

    /**
     * Show the menu popup anchored to the view specified during construction.
     *
     * @see #dismiss()
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public void show() {
        mPopup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Dismiss the menu popup.
     *
     * @see #show()
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public void dismiss() {
        mPopup.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Set a listener that will be notified when the user selects an item from the menu.
     *
     * @param listener Listener to notify
     */
    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
        mMenuItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set a listener that will be notified when this menu is dismissed.
     *
     * @param listener Listener to notify
     */
    public void setOnDismissListener(OnDismissListener listener) {
        mDismissListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menu, MenuItem item) {
        if (mMenuItemClickListener != null) {
            return mMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onCloseMenu(MenuBuilder menu, boolean allMenusAreClosing) {
        if (mDismissListener != null) {
            mDismissListener.onDismiss(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public boolean onOpenSubMenu(MenuBuilder subMenu) {
        if (subMenu == null) return false;

        if (!subMenu.hasVisibleItems()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Current menu will be dismissed by the normal helper, submenu will be shown in its place.
        new MenuPopupHelper(mContext, subMenu, mAnchor).show();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onCloseSubMenu(SubMenuBuilder menu) {
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {
    }

    /**
     * Interface responsible for receiving menu item click events if the items themselves
     * do not have individual item click listeners.
     */
    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener {
        /**
         * This method will be invoked when a menu item is clicked if the item itself did
         * not already handle the event.
         *
         * @param item {@link MenuItem} that was clicked
         * @return <code>true</code> if the event was handled, <code>false</code> otherwise.
         */
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item);
    }

}
```

And just use this file as,

```
IconizedMenu popup = new IconizedMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.pop_up, popup.getMenu());

popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new IconizedMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
popup.show();//showing popup menu
```

pop_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mathematics"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Mathematics" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/chemistry"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Chemistry" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/physics"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Physics" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/biology"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Biology" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I want to set the icon from `my_layout.xml`, not an image.